# Is there a way to have a secondary storage or backup for data blocks in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, backup, hdfs

I have Hadoop running on a cluster that has non-dedicated nodes (i.e. it shares nodes with other applications/users). When the other users are using a cluster's node, it is not allowed to run Hadoop jobs in that node. Thus, it is possible that only a few nodes are available in a given moment, and that this few nodes do not have all data blocks (replicas) need by the Hadoop job.

I also have a big Network-Attached Storage that is used for backup. So, I am wondering if there is a way to use it as a secondary storage for Hadoop. For example, if some data block is missing in the cluster, Hadoop would get the block from the secondary/backup storage.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware about such a "mixed" storage mode for the hadoop. So I do not think that your scenario is directly supported by hadoop. 
For me it looks like you need more "elastic" solution. If EMR would be available open source - it might be good choice - where NAS would play the role of S3. 
I would suggest the following solution in Your case: 
Install and run data nodes on all available servers. They are not as resource hungy as task trackers - since they are only sequentially read/write data. 
Install task trackers on all machines also, but run only on these which are not used now. Hadoop is smart enough to preserve data locality when possible. In the same time hadoop will takes change in number of task trackers much easier then disappearing data nodes. 
Alternatively you can build cluster of task trackers only, not use HDFS and run jobs against the NAS. 
In all cases the main interference with other users I still expect is network congestions - during shuffle stage hadoop is usually saturating the network.

Comment: Great! I took a look at EMR/S3 and I think it is exactly what I need. :-) I don't know if there is something like that for private clouds/clusters, and also open source. So, I am planning try your suggestion and create some scripts to workaround possible issues. Thanks a lot.